# Various "Undefined" notices on content admin screen

Tags: 7

I get these sporadically on the content admin screens.  These seem to be referencing fields that I do have in my templates, that are working just fine for those actual screens.  I just don't get why this content admin screen would be looking for those values.

Here are the error messages:

```
•   Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$field_pcast_fname in include() (line 64 of /mnt/drive2/vhosts/ainonline.com/httpdocs/drupal/sites/all/themes/ain_core/templates/node.tpl.php).
•   Notice: Undefined variable: messages in include() (line 13 of /mnt/drive2/vhosts/ainonline.com/httpdocs/drupal/sites/all/themes/ain_core/templates/comment-wrapper.tpl.php).
•   Notice: Undefined index: field_twithandle in include() (line 14 of /mnt/drive2/vhosts/ainonline.com/httpdocs/drupal/sites/all/themes/ain_core/templates/user-profile.tpl.php).
•   Notice: Undefined variable: field_headshot in include() (line 24 of /mnt/drive2/vhosts/ainonline.com/httpdocs/drupal/sites/all/themes/ain_core/templates/user-profile.tpl.php).
•   Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in include() (line 94 of /mnt/drive2/vhosts/ainonline.com/httpdocs/drupal/sites/all/themes/ain_core/templates/user-profile.tpl.php).
•   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in include() (line 94 of /mnt/drive2/vhosts/ainonline.com/httpdocs/drupal/sites/all/themes/ain_core/templates/user-profile.tpl.php).
```

And for example, the field_twithandle code that's in my user-profile.tpl.php:

```
<?php if($user_profile['field_twithandle']) { ?> 
    <div class="profile_twitfollow">
        <a href="http://twitter.com/<?php print $field_twithandle[0]['value']; ?>" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-show-screen-name="false">Follow @<?php print $field_twithandle[0]['value']; ?></a>
        <script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </div>
<?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, check to make sure it's set first:

```
<?php if (isset($field_twithandle[0]['value'])): ?>
<a href="http://twitter.com/<?php print $field_twithandle[0]['value']; ?>" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-show-screen-name="false">Follow @<?php print $field_twithandle[0]['value']; ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The problem is that those values aren't set on some pages, which is why you're getting the error. So that's a fix for an undefined index error. You also have things like undefined variable, for which a fix could be like:

```
<?php if (isset($messages)): ?>
  /* Do stuff here with $messages */
<?php endif; ?>
```